# Limit of expected empirical risk as the number of samples grow

Tags: machine-learning

Consider $2N$ i.i.d random variables $x_1,\dots, x_{2N}$ drawn from an unknown distribution $X$. Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $f(X)$ has finite mean and variance. For $1\leq n\leq 2N$, suppose $\epsilon_n \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$ is an i.i.d white noise and $\mathbb E[x_n\epsilon_n]=0$.  Define $y_n=f(x_n) + \epsilon_n$. The first $N$ samples will be the training set and the remainder will be the test set.

Consider a model class $\mathcal M$, such that every model $m\in \mathcal M$ is unbiased and has finite variance. Our loss function is MSE. It's easy to see that the expected training loss is
$$MSE_{train}(m)=\sigma^2 + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E\left[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2-2m(x_n)\epsilon_n\right]$$
Intuitively, I thought that as the number of training samples grows, the term $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E\left[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2\right]$ will approach the model's expected MSE loss, ie.

$$\mathbb E[(f(X)-m(X))^2]=\int_I X(f(X)-m(X))^2dX$$, where $I$ is the support of $X$.

In particular, I am hypothesizing that if $N\to\infty$, then a model trained on the training data will have an equal expected fit of $f$, ie. $\mathbb E[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2]$ on any sample $x_n$ for $1\leq n\leq 2N$.

Note this, intuitively, can be true even if $m$ memorizes the training data because, with a large number of samples, it can be said that the unseen data is very close to the data $m$ saw before training.

Here is my attempt to prove it:

If parameters of $m\in\mathcal M$ are independent of $x_1,\dots,x_{N}$, the result is obvious. So, let us assume $m$ is conditioned on $x_1,\dots, x_N$.

Since $m$ has a finite variance, the Law of Large Numbers can be applied for $N$ large enough. I will also use an identity: for random variables $A, B$ with finite mean and variance, we have $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[A|B]]=\mathbb E\left[A\right]$.

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2|x_1,\dots,x_N\right] &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E\left[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2|x_1,\dots,x_N\right]\\ 
&=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[(f(X)-m(X))^2|x_1,\dots,x_N\right]\right]\\ 
&= \mathbb E\left[(f(X)-m(X))^2\right]\\ 
&= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\mathbb E\left[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2\right]
\end{align}

**Questions**

1. Is this hypothesis even true? Do I need to impose more restrictions on $f$ and $\mathcal M$ before I can say that?
2. Is my above attempt at proving this hypothesis correct?

Comment: If all you want is to show that the term
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E\left[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2\right] $$ converges to $\mathbb E[(f(X)-m(X))^2]$ as $N\to\infty$, then it is immediately true. In fact, something much stronger is true : for any $N\ge1$, you have the **equality**
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E\left[(f(x_n)-m(x_n))^2\right] = \mathbb E[(f(X)-m(X))^2]$$
which is clear if you remember that the $x_n$'s are i.i.d. and follow the distribution of $X$. Is it really what you want to prove though ?

Comment: $m$ is trained on the training dataset (ie. the parameters of $m$ are conditioned on $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$). I think in that case the 2nd equality you suggested is not true, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also note that the model $m$ is the output of a training algorithm hence is a function of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (and usually we will denote it $\hat m$ to highlight the fact that it is a function of the sample), so 1) your summation indices should be $N+1\le n\le 2N$ and 2) we need to know if you are computing the expected MSE over $x_1,\ldots,x_{2N}$, $x_N,\ldots,x_{2N}$ or $x_1,\ldots,x_{N}$

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. 1) Why do you think the summation indices need to be in $N+1\leq n\leq 2N$? Could you please clarify what you mean by 2)? Is it the term $\mathbb E[{(m(X)-f(X))^2}]$?

Comment: 1) Because $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ are the *training* sample, so when you compute the MSE you compute the error on the *testing* sample which if I understood your post correctly should be $x_{N+1},\ldots,x_{2N}$. Regarding my point 2) I am simply asking, since $M_N:=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N} (f(x_n) - m(x_n))^2$ is a random variable which depends on both the training and testing sample (i.e. depends on $x_1,\ldots,x_{2N}$), when you take the expectation $\mathbb E[M_N]$, should it be understood as $\mathbb E_{x_1,\ldots, x_{2N}}[M_N]$ or something else ?

Comment: 1) You can define MSE loss on the training data, it's called [empirical risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization_error), and the indices are correctly from $1\leq n\leq N$. The overall intuition I have is that with certain restrictions on the model class $\mathcal M$ and regulatory conditions, the more data the model is trained on, the better it fits $f$. I am asking if I need to impose more restrictions on $\mathcal M$ to say this. The expected MSE, in this case, would be $$\mathbb E[(f(x)-m(x))^2]=\int_I x(f(x)-m(x))^2dx$$, where $I$ is the support of $X$.

Comment: I'll try another explanation (English is not my first language): the informal argument I have is: if $m$ is conditioned on a lot of data points, its fit of $f(X)$, ie. ($(f(x)-m(x))^2$) is "approximately" same in both the training and in the test data.

Comment: The empirical risk is meant to be a measure of how well your model performs on unseen data (how it "generalizes"), so naturally it shouldn't be measured on the data it has been trained with in the first place, since by construction it is going to perform very well on that "already seen" data (that's also what is mentioned in the Wikipedia page you linked). Furthermore, if you really measure the MSE on the datapoints $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ and you trained the model on $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ (by *definition* of the training data), then the testing data $x_{N+1},\ldots,x_{2N}$ is useless !

Comment: I think your last conclusion about the test dataset is contradictory to what you said in the beginning. 
"The empirical risk is meant to be a measure of how well your model performs on unseen data"

This is why we need the unseen data points above.

Comment: Ok, please clarify : you write in your post that *"the first $N$ sample will be the training set and the remainder will be the test set"*, which I understand as $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ are the **training** data so they are **seen** by the model during the training, while $x_{N+1},\ldots,x_{2N}$ are the **testing** data so they are **unseen** by the model and can be used to *test* the generalization error of the model. This is taken verbatim for your question, so please edit and clarify

Comment: Your last comment agrees with having training and a test set. Now I am even less sure about what you're confused about. Could you please state what *you think* the question is about? I am asking because, in your first comment, you used the IID variables to derive a wrong equation. Next, you did not understand the training and test datasets. I am trying to make the question as clear as possible. Therefore, I would really appreciate some feedback!

Comment: Do you not see that the **training set** is given for $1\le n \le N$ while the **testing set** is given for the indices $N+1\le n \le 2N$ ? So if the MSE is for the **testing data** (as it should be) then the summation indices should go from $N+1$ to $2N$, which is *not* what you've written. This is super confusing especially because $m$ is a function of the **training set** $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ (which, again, you don't make explicit in your notation). If you don't see where the confusion comes from then I can't help you further.

Comment: @StratosFair I have edited the question!